List Column not showing up in my SharePoint List but it is showing up in my List Settings

I created a list and columns but not all my columns are showing up in my list. You can see the "Attendees" column on the list settings page, But this column does not show up on my list.
Please Help. I am spinning my wheels.

Where do you want to see this column exactly, in list "view" or in list "form"?
